# Postgres getting transition table columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a way to get a modified/inserted columns list of the transition table in a trigger function?

i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 text NOT NULL, c2 integer);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('tup1', 10), ('tup2', 20);

CREATE FUNCTION show_modified_tups() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
r1 record;
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    FOR r1 IN SELECT * FROM old_table
    LOOP
        raise notice 'OLD: %', r1;
    END loop;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    FOR r1 IN SELECT * FROM new_table
    LOOP
        raise notice 'NEW: %', r1;
    END loop;
    FOR r1 IN SELECT * FROM old_table
    LOOP
        raise notice 'OLD: %', r1;
    END loop;
ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    FOR r1 IN SELECT * FROM new_table
    LOOP
        raise notice 'NEW: %', r1;
    END loop;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t1_ins
 AFTER INSERT ON t1 REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table
 FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE show_modified_tups();

CREATE TRIGGER t1_upd
 AFTER UPDATE ON t1 REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table NEW TABLE AS new_table
 FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE show_modified_tups();

CREATE TRIGGER t1_del
 AFTER DELETE ON t1 REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS old_table
 FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE show_modified_tups();
```

*(taken from https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/Postgres-Gems/Can-modified-tuples-be-accessed-using-a-statement-level-trigger/ba-p/2416)*

I am inserting a line into the table:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES('tup5')
```

I want to get a list of inserted/updated columns in transition table `new_table` (i.e. `(c1)` in our case)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The structure of the transition table is the same as the structure of the triggering table.

Use `TG_RELID` or `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME` to query `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` or `information_schema.columns` for the definition.

Comment: As mentioned in the question - I'd like to know which columns were actually inserted/updated.

Comment: Oh, I see. In PostgreSQL, all columns are updated or inserted, no matter how your statement looks. The best you can do is to compare the old and new values, but if they are equal, that is no proof that they didn't appear in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`.